# Sample size estimation with known mean (optimal value), unknown stdv

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, sample-size

quick question on sample size estimation. Let's say i play a game of poker, where i have 2 options, play or don't play. In the long run, the optimal strategy is to play 15% of all times, dependent on my 2 cards, from the first position.

Now i play the game with a variety of players. Some will of course deviate from the optimal strategy, and play 40%, or 10% of all times. The question is how many samples do i have to take of a particular player to have a significant value of his playing percentage strategy so that i can decide whether he deviates from game theoretical optimum or not. If i have only a sample of 10 hands on that position, the player could be just lucky and had 5 times good hands and played 50% of all times, or 5 times weak holdings and still played 50% of all times.

First, i thought i use a chi-square test, but then i found Cochran's formula, which is probably doing the same job. A quick suggestion on what i have to look for is highly appreciated.

EDIT:
Seems like i wasn't concrete enough. Let me give an example. There are 1326 possible holdings in texas hold'em poker, from AA to 72. Let's say, from early position, one should raise according to the game-theoretical optimum, outcome from nash solver, 15,5% of all hands, or 205 combos, and fold the rest.

Now i just record how often 1 opponent did raise from early position every time he had the opportunity to do so. Since i will not play forever against this player, my sample size will be finite. 
The question is, how big the sample size has to be, to get a significant (whatever effect size and according confidence value, and power i will choose for my hypothesis test) value for this player. I believe it is not a proportion which i look at, but a mean. The standard deviation from the optimal value is unknown.

First i thought about a chi square test, like testing if a die is fair. If let's say the raising frequency should be 50%, then i would just use a chi square test for a die with 2 sides, choose significance level, effect size, and power, and 1 degree of freedom. Problem with this approach is that its obviously limited to all cases where i got natural numbers for the degrees of freedom.

I just want to get an idea which test routine i should use, i can look into the mathematics by myself ofc. I dont want to run Monte Carlo sims, since i think this is a simple to solve problem, and just my lack of experience on sample size estimation holds me from seeing the obvious approach.

Best

Ray